# Debugging Cassandra in CQLSH - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am running some Cassandra queries. When I run

```
select * from logtable;
```

I get this error:

```
<ErrorMessage code=0000 [Server error] message="java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException">
```

However, if I run with limits, some rows are OK:

```
select * from logtable limit 100;
```

This works. I keep increasing the limit and eventually, I get the error again. It's obvious that our software adds some corrupted data. My question is this: is there a way to find out what is happening using cqlsh? I can't study the code, because it's extremely messed up, it's a nightmare. I couldn't find anything useful in system.log.
This is the table:

```
cqlsh:mykeyspace> desc table logtable

CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.logtable (
    key text,
    key2 text,
    column1 text,
    column2 text,
    column3 text,
    column4 text,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY ((key, key2), column1, column2, column3, column4)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE
    AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (column1 ASC, column2 ASC, column3 ASC, column4 ASC)
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = 'NONE';
```

Thanks.

Regards,
Serban

Comment: Can you post the output of `> show version`?

Comment: There's likely a stacktrace in logs/system.log, too - any chance you can find that?

Comment: We need a Java exception stack trace to work out the origin of the issue